# Add search icon on action bar android

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, icons

Good days guys.

I have a search icon in action bar as image below

[image]

When it is clicked, I want the action bar change to `editText` and has a search `icon` beside the `editText`

I know how to make an editText with an image, but how to put the editText on the action bar like image below ? And I want to make the data display value once the editText has filled with value. Should I use intent ?

[image]

This is what I've tried so far.

**Activity A**

```
 getData(deviceName, month); // retrieve data from `MySQL` and load into listView

        @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.create_menu, menu); 
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            mSearchAction = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.search: // should I need to add intent ?
                    handleMenuSearch();
                    return true;

                case R.id.add: // create new file
                    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.add);
                    PopupMenu po = new PopupMenu(HomePage.this, menuItemView); //for drop-down menu
                    po.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, po.getMenu());
                    po.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if ("Create New File".equals(item.getTitle())) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Information.class);  // go to Information class
                                startActivity(intent);

                            } else if ("Edit File".equals(item.getTitle())) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Edit.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    po.show(); //showing popup menu

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        protected void handleMenuSearch(){
            ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar

            if(isSearchOpened){ //test if the search is open

                action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); //disable a custom view inside the actionbar
                action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show the title in the action bar

                //hides the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtSeach.getWindowToken(), 0);

                //add the search icon in the action bar
                mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.search));

                isSearchOpened = false;
            } else { //open the search entry

                action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a
                // custom view in the action bar.
                action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);//add the custom view
                action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title

                edtSeach = (EditText)action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch); //the text editor

                //this is a listener to do a search when the user clicks on search button
                edtSeach.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                            doSearch();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                edtSeach.requestFocus();

                //open the keyboard focused in the edtSearch
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(edtSeach, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


                //add the close icon
                mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.search));

                isSearchOpened = true;
            }
        }

      @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(isSearchOpened) {
                handleMenuSearch();
                return;
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        private void doSearch() {
    //
        }


    }
```

**Screen shot of Activity A**

[image]

When search icon is pressed, it supposed to intent to another page and have a search icon on the editText (exactly like the second image), but it didn't. It remains in the same page.

[image]

This is what I want (From wechat)

Before icon pressed

[image]

After pressed

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That widget name is: `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

**In your menu:**

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:title="@string/srch"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

**Java:**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

This is exactly like `MaterialDesign` icon.

```
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
```

Comment: Sir should I use intent when search icon is clicked so that the related data get display when editText filled with value ?

Comment: That depends on your expect, with my answer you can use that without using intent.

Comment: android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"

Comment: Use androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView in XML as well as Java class if you have updated to Android X.

Comment: with androidx, it is androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView now.

Answer (score 14):

You should use inbuilt android SearchView this hold good according Android UI Patterns

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.home.activities.TransactionSearchActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Activity code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_transaction_search, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
            searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClose() {
                 //some operation
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //some operation
                }
            });
            EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchPlate.setHint("Search");
            View searchPlateView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
            searchPlateView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
            // use this method for search process
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // use this method when query submitted
                    Toast.makeText(context, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    // use this method for auto complete search process
                    return false;
                }
            });
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            findViewById(R.id.default_title).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

make sure to inflate menu :D

Comment: can you check my post again ? should I use intent ?

Comment: you update your data in the same activity where you are using this option menu. No Intent is required for this.

Comment: so when the back button (beside the editText) is clicked, it will show back the January listView ?

Comment: Instead of getting the "searchPlate" EditText and using `searchPlate.setHint("Search");`, you can just use `searchView.setQueryHint("Search");`.