# SearchView is inside overflow menu when using androidx libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, searchview, androidx

Hi I recently changed my android project to use **androidx** libraries due to some conflicts.

But now, the **SearchView** in my **Toolbar** is shown inside the overflow menu ( just shows 'Search' inside it, nothing happens when I click it ) 
which wasn't the case when using the old support libraries.

[Click here for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp3tk.png)

I need the old iconified Search View back. Please help.

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:logo="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>
```

my menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/search"/>
```

and in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem( R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    return true;
}
```

If it helps, my activity is also a androidx AppCompatActivity

I went through androidx documentation in android developers website and also many stackoverflow questions but no luck. This issue is a first it seems..

Answer (score 2):

> nothing happens when I click it

Nothing happens because you set it `always|collapseActionView` which means you should place the `SearchView` like this:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha" <!-- You can change this.. -->
        android:title="@string/srch"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" 
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

Check my complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34825224/4409113

Comment: This didn't work as I have stated, I am using the **androidx** support libraries and in it, adding searchview to toolbar places it inside a overflow menu although there is only one action in the toolbar. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't notice the Androidx one. How about updated answer? Would you try and see what happens?

Comment: I changed **always** to **ifRoom** in the menu item and that didn't change a thing.

Comment: It does not opens or collapse when you click on it? Do you have to use `androidx` `actionViewClass`? Because i think it should work with the provided link.

Comment: Yes because I am also using other widgets from androidx. Do you think this could be a bug or something in the androidx library ?? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Well i have never seen or used this class: `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` might be a new one but i think, in the link which i have provided in the question should help and will work with `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. If it didn't, might be a bug or sth and i'll give it a try.

Comment: I think you need to use `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"` instead of `android:actionViewClass...`